# Get inner elements as a List from a List

Tags: c#

I have a class like this

```
class Man
{
 int age;
 int height;
}
```

And creating a list like this

```
List<Man> student_list = new List<Man>();
```

1. need to get `age` list from  `student_list`  as a `List<int>`. Is it possible without loop trough the list?
2. need to get list of `Man`  from  `student_list` that `age = 20` as a `List<Man>`. Is it possible without loop trough the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Alter your model to include a public property called `Age` (as opposed to a private field) and then you can use `Select` over the collection:

   ```
   IEnumerable<int> ages = student_list.Select(student => student.Age);
   ```
2. Use `Where` in combination with `ToList` like this:

   ```
   List<Man> students = student_list.Where(student => student.Age == 20).ToList();
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the one shot answer. I have eddied the question. can you help me to answer second one too.

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya Hi Nayana. Would you please consider marking this answer as the accepted one?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this using LINQ to Objects:

```
// Get the students ages
List<int> ages = (from student in student_list select student.age).ToList();

// Get only 20 years old students
List<Man> students = (from student in student_list where student.age == 20 select student).ToList();
```